# Keep Big Object List in memory or Read From File .NET

Tags: winforms, performance, list, memory

I need to read a Big List of Object(each object contains 2 String and 1 Int32) (i extract those object from a XML WebPage), it should contains like 10000 Objects.

I need take from this list about 20 records each minute.

I would know if in terms of performance and for the memory safe , it's better keep this List in memory and take those 20 records (every min) or download The Xml from WebPage , read it from Local Disk each minute and find those 20 records.

Any other solutions would be accepted too :)

Update : Forgot to say i'm talking about a Winform C# Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first rule of optimisation is to measure before optimising.

When you load all the objects into memory how much memore does it consume?  How much more memory do you need for the rest of your app?  How much memory does the machine have?  Are you running in a 32 or 64 bit address space?  How much memory do any other required apps need at the same time?

Once you've answered these questions you can then start to break down your approach to optimisation.  In this case you need 20 records each minute, any 20 records?  Do you need to iterate through all 10,000 to find the 20?  How often does the XML file change?

P.S. Look at XmlReader vs XmlDocument for parsing the XML file.

Comment: The problem is that the machine has 512 max 1GB ram and the most of Times are VirtualMachine. It run on 32bit. And Yes i need to iterate 1000 to find 20 records(but not any 20 , i need to chose them according to the ID field. Xml Changes each 15-20 mins

Comment: At the moment i'm using XmlDocument , but i'm going to see the XmlReader too.

Comment: Thanks i read about the XmlDocument and i must use XmlReader in my case!! now The problem is ...How could i change all in XmlReader?:)

Comment: How much memory do you use when you parse the whole XML file into a more efficient datastrucutre than XmlDocument?  Look at XmlWriter in order to modify the input XML file.

Answer (score 0):

For performance, you'll be much better off to avoid disk I/O.

For memory, both solutions will be the same unless you process the file a line at a time (which is going to give horrible performance, since you won't be able to hash/index the results).

If there is a "key" I would keep them in memory in a dictionary.

If in doubt, profile.